# onFormSubmit missing email on resubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

onFormSubmit for Apps Script seems to not collect email info in resubmits. I have a form with just one question because it's something of an automated way to distribute unique and private codes. Users can submit only once and have to belong to our org.

Having noticed this interesting behavior, I created a dummy to test it below:

I have a form tied to a sheet for responses and on that sheet, I have some code that gets called on a form submit

```
function SubmitGoogleFormData(e) {
 
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
  }
 
  try {
    Logger.log('jsonify of E')
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    var arrayOfValues = e.values
    Logger.log("e.values toString")
    Logger.log(arrayOfValues.toString())
    Logger.log('the range:')
    Logger.log(e.range.toString())
    var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    Logger.log(email_address)
    for (var i in e.namedValues) {
     Logger.log("Question " + i + " = " + e.namedValues[i]);
    }
    Logger.log("e should be above here")
 
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}
```

Since I'm testing, this is really just dummy code that spits out the contents of the submit data. If a new user submits, email address comes through and everything looks great, like so:
[image: log of 1st submit with "redacted" email]

If I clear my response from the form and resubmit, it looks like all the new info is included in the new submission EXCEPT for my email address, like so:
[image: log of second submit where email is '']

Any idea of where the email address would be going/ how to get it to show up? Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. How exactly are you clearing the response and resubmit?.

Comment: When you resubmit the response - are you still logged in with the same account? And is it an account from the same organisation like the user who installed the trigger for formSubmit?

Comment: @Rubén I go back to the form's edit view, responses, then either select the individual response and clear it or, on this test on, I choose the option to clear all responses. same result either way

Comment: @ziganotschka yes, I am still logged in with the same account. All the accounts that can submit are from the same org as the user who installed the trigger, which happens to be me:). I actually do see it with other users too. (i.e. someone wants to change their response, I clear it, they resubmit, and the trigger fires with e having an empty email address value)

Comment: Did you change the settings for this form recently regarding the collection of email addresses? https://gyazo.com/1dcda3e2266a0c8838dfc75378ba6b9d

Comment: @ziganotschka Nope, didn't change a a thing. If you notice in the screenshots, those executions are 2 minutes apart. The only thing i did between submissions was clear the first response